# How to return null instead of fragment in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to return null instead of fragment in react based on somecondition...
if condition is true then render the component if not should return null.

Below is the code...

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        {condition_1 && condition_2 &&
            <ChildComponent
                    name="name1"
                    value="name2"
            />
        }
    </Fragment>
);
```

In the above code if condition_1 and condition_2 is true i am rendering the childcomponent if not fragment..

i want to return null instead of empty fragment when condition_1 and condition_2 fails...

Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
return (
  condition_1 &&
  condition_2 && (
    <Fragment>
      <ChildComponent name="name1" value="name2" />
    </Fragment>
  )
);
```

or if you prefer using ternary operators:

```
return condition_1 && condition_2 ? (
  <Fragment>
    <ChildComponent name="name1" value="name2" />
  </Fragment>
) : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!condition_1 || !condition_2) {
  return null;
}

return (
    <Fragment>
      <ChildComponent
        name="name1"
        value="name2"
      />
    </Fragment>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the conditions out of the fragment and conditionnaly returns null accordingly:

```
    return condition_1 && condition_2
        ? (
            <Fragment>
                <ChildComponent
                    name="name1"
                    value="name2"
                />
            </Fragment>
        )
        : null;
```